# FreeBSD executes linux file, with "ELF binary type "3" not known." error

Tags: linux, freebsd

I followed the instructions on [FreeBSD Handbook](http://docs.freebsd.org/doc/8.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/freebsd/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html), but it doesn't work.

```
$ pkg_info | grep linux_base
linux_base-f10-10_4 Base set of packages needed in Linux mode for i386/amd64 (L
$ kldstat | grep linux
 5    1 0xffffffff8112d000 1c4ac    linux.ko
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64
ELF binary type "3" not known.
./wkhtmltoimage-amd64: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.
$ uname -ai
FreeBSD xxxxxx.xxx.xxx 8.1-RELEASE-p1 FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p1 #0: Mon Oct 18 01:46:34 CST 2010     root@xxxxxx.xxx.xxx:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/CSSULA  amd64 CSSULA
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the "-amd64" suffix, you appear to be attempting to execute a 64-bit binary using Linux emulation... this isn't supported according to numerous sources including e.g. [this](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=29389) thread.